# Reconciling God of Israel refusal of King David's request to build a temple, & (2 Corinthians 5:17-19) new creature in Jesus Christ

Tags: contradiction, creation, sin, temple, atonement

> 1 Chronicles 22:8-10 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>   **8 But the
>   word of the Lord came to me, saying, ‘You have shed much blood and
>   have [d]waged great wars; you shall not build a house to My name,
>   because you have shed so much blood on the earth before Me.** 9 Behold,
>   a son will be born to you, who shall be a man of rest; and I will give
>   him rest from all his enemies on every side; for his name shall be
>   [e]Solomon, and I will give peace and quiet to Israel in his days. 10
>   He shall build a house for My name, and he shall be My son and I will
>   be his father; and I will establish the throne of his kingdom over
>   Israel forever.’
>
> 2 Corinthians 5:17-19 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>    **17 Therefore
>   if anyone is in Christ, [h]he is a new creature; the old things passed
>   away; behold, new things have come. 18 Now all these things are from
>   God, who reconciled us to Himself through Christ and gave us the
>   ministry of reconciliation, 19 namely, that God was in Christ
>   reconciling the world to Himself, not counting their trespasses
>   against them, and [i]He has [j]committed to us the word of
>   reconciliation.**

-Since King David is a follower of The God of Israel, and genuinely repents for his sins ( e.g., repented for adultery with Bathsheba, murder of Uriah, taking of the census of Israel, etc.) then why does God still remind King David about his past life where he 'shed much blood and have waged great wars...", and furthermore denies King David the request to build the Temple of God, but rather tells King David to instruct his son, Solomon, to build said Temple of God?

-Furthermore in 2 Corinthians 5:17-19, once we are in Jesus Christ( or in King David's case, a follower of The God of Israel), we are a new creature, therefore why again does God still remind King David of his past sins?

Comment: I think the matter of regeneration (and, hence, a new creation) is not relevant. Public office requires reputation, whatever the context. Paul's prescriptions regarding bishops and deacons are an example - lack of the possibility of impeachment being a consideration. Recovery and repentance and genuine regeneration are not the issue. Reputation is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Without doing any exegesis, I would just say that shedding blood, and especially killing, changes a person. I saw that in the military a lot. That violence--indeed all of our past--becomes a part of who we are. So even if/when God forgives, as he did with David, we are still changed by the events.

I have been sober from alcohol for almost 20 years, but in meetings I still identify as an alcoholic. Yes, God has forgiven and I am even a new creation, but my alcoholic past will always be a part of me. The difference is that now it is a strength that God uses for his purposes.

Comment: The site actually expects exegesis to be done. 'Without doing any exegesis' is not really appropriate. And you have not covered the main aspect of the question - the matter of _reputation_. Past actions affect reputation and future responsibilities require reputation, is the point.

Comment: Hello kiswarior, welcome to BHSE, glad to have you with us. If you haven't already, please make sure to take our tour, to see how we are a little different from other sites you may know. Thanks! (hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: you have not covered the main aspect of the question - the matter of reputation. Past actions affect reputation and future responsibilities require reputation, is the point. – @Nigel J yesterday
 Well, that's a fine howdy do. You ding me for no exegesis and then offer none of your own. You have only hijacked the question to put your own spin on it--reputation. Pure exegesis is about the text, not your worldview. But as  long as we're bringing in Paul, lets bring in Jesus, son of David, who cared not a whit about his reputation.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the Lord wanted to establish His kingdom in a time of rest and peace and not midst struggle and torment. We can see this earlier in Genesis where God doesn't choose to establish His temple (Eden) until after He "rests" from His work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).